# C# Verify that 2 textboxes contain text

Tags: c#, if-statement, text

What I am trying to do is make a button disabled when the text boxes have no text in them and when text does occupy the desired textboxes the button becomes enabled

```
if (NamePath.Text.Length == 0 && ThemePath.Text.Length == 0)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
}
else if (NamePath.Text.Length > 0 && ThemePath.Text.Length > 0)
{
     button1.Enabled = true;
     label7.Text = "Press Button To Find a Match";
     label7.ForeColor = Color.PaleGreen;
}
```

EDIT:

I tried a different method which I added text to the textbox to try and trigger it but still no luck :/

```
            if (NamePath.Text == "yes" && ThemePath.Text == "yes")
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;

        }

        if (NamePath.Text != "yes" && ThemePath.Text != "yes")
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
            label7.Text = "Press Button To Find a Match";
            label7.ForeColor = Color.PaleGreen;

        }
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're expecting to see with your code, and what you're actually seeing? I've had a try at an answer, but I'm making some assumptions.

Comment: what event is firing(to run the code above) and how do you hooked them up?

Comment: I have it in the public Form1() so it starts when opened, its disabled as the code tells it to, its the ability to enable it that is not working right.

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting the button to be enabled when either of the text boxes has text in it?

If so, you could use an else statement:

```
if (NamePath.Text.Length == 0 && ThemePath.Text.Length == 0)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
     button1.Enabled = true;
     label7.Text = "Press Button To Find a Match";
     label7.ForeColor = Color.PaleGreen;
}
```

As it stands, there is nothing handling when there is text in only one of the fields.

If you wanted to verify that both boxes contain text, you can flip the logic around.

```
if (NamePath.Text.Length > 0 && ThemePath.Text.Length > 0)
{
     button1.Enabled = true;
     label7.Text = "Press Button To Find a Match";
     label7.ForeColor = Color.PaleGreen;
} else {
    button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Please describe what you're seeing vs. what you expect to see in your question. We don't know what "isn't working" actually means, and so any further suggestions would just be guesswork.

Comment: When the 2 text boxes contain text nothing happens they stay disabled

Comment: Might be that you're not referring to them using the right names or similar. I'd suggest adding a line to log the content of the boxes before the if statement to see what your code thinks is in them.